# Set progressbar to KB and MB instead of % for android download manager

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog, filesize

I'm trying to download an image from url and I need to display the size of the file and the progress of the file downloading.

This is what I have.

```
 int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

 final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getFileSize(fileSizeInKB);
                        mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

                    }
  });

As of now its showing %(ie..10/100)
```

If I set it to **`mProgressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d kb / %2d kB")`**
its showing as **`1kb of 100kb`** but unable to get the actual size of the file which I'm trying to download

I need it display as **1.2MB/3.6MB**

Issue is the progress is displaying as seen below 60/100 but I don't want that

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by *but unable to get the actual size of the file which I'm trying to download*,?

Comment: @Blackbelt- Unable to get in the sense how do I display the actual size of the file in the progressbar instead of the %

Comment: did you check if the content-length is set ?

Comment: What's exactly the issue?

Comment: ok. So the max of your progress is `bytes_total`, isn't it ?

Comment: yes exactly thats the max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally made it to work:

Here is the way

```
long  downloadedsize, filesize;
public static final double SPACE_KB = 1024;
public static final double SPACE_MB = 1024 * SPACE_KB;
public static final double SPACE_GB = 1024 * SPACE_MB;
public static final double SPACE_TB = 1024 * SPACE_GB;
```

and set this to progressbar

```
mProgressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat((bytes2String(downloadedsize)) + "/" + (bytes2String(filesize)));
```

Method: Converting byte to string

```
public static String bytes2String(long sizeInBytes) {

        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        try {
            if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_KB ) {
                return nf.format(sizeInBytes) + " Byte(s)";
            } else if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_MB ) {
                return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_KB) + " KB";
            } else if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_GB ) {
                return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_MB) + " MB";
            } else if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_TB ) {
                return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_GB) + " GB";
            } else {
                return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_TB) + " TB";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return sizeInBytes + " Byte(s)";
        }

  }
```

Comment: How to find size of  **total** and **lengthOfFile**

Comment: @Gowthaman M See this: http://www.androiddeft.com/android-download-file-from-url-with-progress-bar/. Kinda late, but always good to put here.