# Show File Download Progress in MB

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm downloading a mp3 file from the internet and saving it into the internal storage. The progress of the download is shown in a `ProgressDialog`. The `ProgressDialog` displays the progress in percent which is fine. In the right it displays the progress as 1/100 .... I'd like it to display the current size of the file downloaded in MB / the total size of the file being downloaded in MB.

Like in the following picture. The grey text is the current text being displayed. I'd like it to be displayed like the text below it in red.

[image]

Here's the current code :

```
public class DownloadSKHindi extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading");
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            url = new URL(skURL[10]);

            connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            OutputStream output = getActivity().openFileOutput(file.getPath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lengthOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to do some calculation. first get file size and then check each percent in byte and then convert it to MB

Comment: @Devansh How to find size of  **total** and **lengthOfFile**

Comment: @GowthamanM as you can see above, `lengthOfFile` is obtained by getting the length of the file that i was connecting to. So whatever file you're trying to download using the `AsyncTask`, just use `connection.getContentLength();` for `lengthOfFile` .    `total` shows how much of the file has been downloaded. The code is already there for it above

Comment: @ Devansh Thanks bro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `total` is how many bytes are downloaded, and `lengthOfFile` is the size in bytes of how large the file is. You can do this:

```
progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat((bytes2String(total)) + "/" + (bytes2String(lengthOfFile)));
```

Then using the function bytes2String ( Credit to [coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/944919/coder) )

```
private static double SPACE_KB = 1024;
private static double SPACE_MB = 1024 * SPACE_KB;
private static double SPACE_GB = 1024 * SPACE_MB;
private static double SPACE_TB = 1024 * SPACE_GB;

public static String bytes2String(long sizeInBytes) {

    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    try {
        if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_KB ) {
            return nf.format(sizeInBytes) + " Byte(s)";
        } else if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_MB ) {
            return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_KB) + " KB";
        } else if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_GB ) {
            return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_MB) + " MB";
        } else if ( sizeInBytes < SPACE_TB ) {
            return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_GB) + " GB";
        } else {
            return nf.format(sizeInBytes/SPACE_TB) + " TB";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return sizeInBytes + " Byte(s)";
    }

}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920150/3522327)

Comment: How to find size of  **total** and **lengthOfFile**

Comment: @GowthamanM that is available in DownloadTask

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextView` that is appended after progressDialog inside XML file.
Consider `TextView tv = findViewById();`

Use this: `publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lengthOfFile), total ,lengthOfFile);` to push new data.

And to update the `tv` use this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
tv.setText((values[1]/(1024*1024)) + "" +(values[1]/(1024*1024)));
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to get the `TextView`, you can use `ProgressBar#setProgressNumberFormat`.

Comment: @JediBurrell , interesting idea, but he wants red huge text

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was just the example. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Yep, that was only for representation. Not what I wanted. But thanks for the answer anyway!